# Choice of ideal so that localisation of a module must be free?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian, finitely-generated

> If $R$ is a Noetherian (commutative) ring and $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, then what choice of nonzero ideal $I$ of $R$ is such that $M_P$ is a free $R_P$-module for any prime $P$ in $R$ such that $P+I=R$?

My idea is to write $M$ as a quotient of a free module, say $R^n/N$, and then let $I=Ann(M)$. I think this means $N_P=0$ for any $P$ as stated, which means $M_P$ is free, but does this $I$ have to be nonzero?

Many thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $U=\{P\in\operatorname{Spec}(R):M_P \text{ is free}\}$ is open in $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ (for a proof see [here](http://books.google.ro/books?id=kHKaeGEpUDwC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=%22MP+is+free%22+open+in+spec&source=bl&ots=kuw0gV4sZH&sig=X3SgWagjeXNSMtowcDGVnKJX7aM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=j-BvU-vzJcmr7AbLxYD4Cw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22MP%20is%20free%22%20open%20in%20spec&f=true)), so there is an ideal $J$ such that $U=\operatorname{Spec}(R)-V(J)$. If $J=(0)$, then $U=\emptyset$ and can take $I=R$; if $J\ne (0)$, take $I=J$.

Comment: Is the book above Lectures on Alg Geometry by Harder and Diederich Vol 2?

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping for a more elementary solution without using Spec, but maybe there isn't one...